# How to set parent-div width according to child-div height?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image here please click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue3Hg.png)How to set parent-div width according to child-div height?
here ".not-consider" class not important but i want set width according height

```
<div class="parent-div">
    <div class="child-div"></div>
    <div class="not-consider"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) What have you tried? What research have you done? What does your attempt to solve the problem look like? Where, specifically, are you stuck?

Comment: try this., $(".parent-div").css("width", $(".child-div").css("width")); if its working then i can post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```js
function resize() {
  var height = $('.child-div').height()
  $('.parent-div').css({
    minWidth: height,
    maxWidth: height,
  })
}

resize()
setInterval(resize, 100)
```

```css
.parent-div {
  background-color: black;
}

.child-div {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent-div">
    <div class="child-div">Child</div>
    <div class="not-consider"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: pls check image that i attached

Answer (score 0):

just use JQuery variable for the child height.
`var child_height= $('.child-div').height();`
then apply this to parent.

`$('.parent-div').css({'width': child_height});`

see this fiddle,
https://jsfiddle.net/saifudazzlings/s41wxpbk/